# Numpy reshaping with a custom ordering

Tags: python, numpy, reshape, numpy-slicing

Is there a way to make a custom order to the reshape function that is not 'C' or 'F'?

I want to take a flat array and make it 3-dimensional by first changing the second index, then changing the third index, and lastly changing the first index?

For example something like

```
a = np.arange(12).reshape((2, 2, 3), (2, 3, 1)) # Second parameter not real numpy
```

resulting in:

```
a[:,:,0] = [[0, 1], [6, 7]]
a[:,:,1] = [[2, 3], [8, 9]]
a[:,:,2] = [[4, 5], [10, 11]]
```

It seems like pretty ordinary functionality but I can't seem to find a way to do it without manually reshaping it myself in loops which is undesirable.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

First, just what did you produce?

```
In [127]: a = np.zeros((2,2,2),int)
In [128]: a = np.zeros((2,2,3),int)
In [129]: a[:,:,0] = [[0, 1], [6, 7]]
     ...: a[:,:,1] = [[2, 3], [8, 9]]
     ...: a[:,:,2] = [[4, 5], [10, 11]]
In [130]: a
Out[130]: 
array([[[ 0,  2,  4],
        [ 1,  3,  5]],

       [[ 6,  8, 10],
        [ 7,  9, 11]]])
```

Now let's try working backwards:

Simple reshape doesn't help:

```
In [131]: a.reshape(2,6)
Out[131]: 
array([[ 0,  2,  4,  1,  3,  5],
       [ 6,  8, 10,  7,  9, 11]])
```

but transposing the last 2 axes:

```
In [132]: a.transpose(0,2,1)
Out[132]: 
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 4,  5]],

       [[ 6,  7],
        [ 8,  9],
        [10, 11]]])
In [133]: a.transpose(0,2,1).reshape(2,6)
Out[133]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

So in the forward direction:

```
In [135]: np.arange(12).reshape(2,3,2).transpose(0,2,1)
Out[135]: 
array([[[ 0,  2,  4],
        [ 1,  3,  5]],

       [[ 6,  8, 10],
        [ 7,  9, 11]]])
```

Comment: although the question screamed np.transpose(), I find the idea of posting the process of finding the solution quite intriguing